# Cloud Page URL in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpagesurl

How can I create or modify the URL for landing pages in Marketing Cloud to not to show cloud in the link or to have the actual website link in the landing page URL.
Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need? Maybe show an example of what you have now and what you would like to be able to do?

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj currently the link for the landing page I created is showing like "https://cloud.e.janssen.com/doubleoptina" but I want it to show like the client website page without cloud that would be like "https://www.lentekontakti.al/acuvue-oasys-1-day-30-lenses". Instead of "cloud.e.janssen.com" i must be able to see only the client website link so is that possible. Please let me know if further clarification required.

Comment: Thanks, in that case please see my answer below - you need to purchase a Custom Domain.

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure 100% what you mean, but seems that you are looking for something like `Custom Domain`:

> Custom Domain for CloudPages - This feature includes a private domain
> for CloudPages

This is a paid feature and you have to contact your account executive to get a quote.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5